# Parsing simple JSON Error

Tags: jquery, html, json, last.fm

I'm trying to parse some simple JSON data and pull out certain parts to display as HTML. All is going well apart from my Last.fm JSON data has a child of `recenttracks.track.artist_text`

The text isn't being translated or picked up properly and (as I'm new to this) cannot figure out why? The reason I believe is something to do with the underscore `_` before the last child.

Everything is working well apart from this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=foo&api_key=bar&format=json&limit=1", function(json) {
  alert("JSON Data: " + json.recenttracks.track.artist._text);
});
</script>
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `text` is defined as a string containing the name of a property of `artist`?

Comment: Is `json.recenttracks.track.artist._text` an intended typo?

Comment: Try json.recenttracks.track.artist["_text"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the JSON that is produced, it looks like you would need to access as:

```
json.recenttracks.track.artist['#text']
```

Here I use bracket syntax to get at the last property `#text`. I don't see where you are getting the underscore in `_text` from as in the JSON it shows as `#text`.